# Git - Compare commits on different branches

Tags: git, git-diff

Say we have the following branches:

```
aaa --> bbb --> ccc --> ddd (HEAD) Branch A

eee --> fff --> ggg Branch B
```

Would it be possible to compare bbb (on Branch A) with eee (on Branch B)?

The following compares the tip of the branches (afaik):

```
git diff A..B
```

While the following compares commits on the same branch:

```
git diff ddd..ccc
```

Would it be possible to merge these parameters?

Comment: You can run `git show b` and `git show e` (it's not really what you're looking for though)

Comment: Why don'y you try it? I am not sure why you think it will not work.

Comment: What's wrong with `git diff bbb eee`?

Comment: Indeed `git diff bbb eee` works.

Comment: Heh. Surprise! :) Commit-ids are not tied to a branch name, they are world wide global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with compare commit heads

git diff head first branch  head second branch

```
git diff 0dae34e  769ffr330c
```